# always MemoryError when asigning and updating values to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling

I need to use a complicated kind of dict and change the values of some keys dynamically.
So I tried it the following way but encountered  with MemoryError with about 32GB RAM. The sys.getsizeof(d) returns 393356 and the sys.getsizeof(d.items()) is 50336.
Did I use the python dict in a wrong way ? can anyone help me !?

```
d=nltk.defaultdict(lambda:nltk.defaultdict(float))
for myarticlewords in mywords:
    for i in myarticlewords:
        for j in myarticlewords:
            d[i][j]+=1.0
```

Traceback stoped at   "d[i][j]+=1.0   "

When I tried :

```
dd=dict( (i,d[i].items() ) for i in d.keys() )

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    dd=dict( (i,d[i].items() ) for i in d.keys() )
   File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <genexpr>
   dd=dict( (i,d[i].items() ) for i in d.keys() )
MemoryError
```

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to investigate using a `shelve`.  Are you using 32 or 64bit version?

Comment: Thanks!I've never heard of shelve before,sounds more useful than pickle!  I'm using 32bit version .

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using a 32-bit version of python. If you're running windows, you've probably hit the [windows memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537759/577088) for 32-bit programs, which is 2GB.

That lines up with the numbers I've calculated based on some educated guesses. First, a few important facts: `getsizeof` only returns the size of the *dict itself*, not of the things stored in it. This is true of all "container" types. Also, dictionaries increase their size in a staggered way, after every so many items are added.

Now, when I store a dictionary with between about 5500 and 21000 items, `getsizeof` returns  `786712` -- i.e. `393356 * 2`. My version of Python is 64-bit, so this strongly suggests to me that you're storing between 5500 and 21000 items using a 32-bit version of Python. You're using `nltk`, which suggests that you're storing word digrams here. So that means you have a minimum of about 5500 words. You're storing a second dictionary for each of those words, which is also a 5500-item dictionary. So what you really have here is `393356 + 393356 * 5500` bytes, plus a minimum of `5500 * 20` bytes for word storage. Summing it all up:

```
>>> (393356 + 393356 * 5500 + 5500 * 20) / 1000000000.0
2.163961356
```

You're trying to store at least 2GB of data. So in short, if you want to make use of those 32 gigabytes of memory, you should upgrade to a 64-bit version of Python.

---

I'll add that if you're concerned about performance, you may just want to use `pickle` (or `cPickle`) rather than `shelve` to store the dictionary. `shelve` will probably be slower, even if you set `writeback=True`.

```
>>> shelve_d = shelve.open('data', writeback=True)
>>> normal_d = {}
>>> def fill(d):
...    for i in xrange(100000):
...        d[str(i)] = i
...        
>>> %timeit fill(shelve_d)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.6 s per loop
>>> %timeit fill(normal_d)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.4 ms per loop
```

Saving the dictionary with `pickle` will take some time too, naturally, but at least it won't slow down the computation itself.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot！I am now using the 64-bit version of Python.But when dealing with big dictionries , it is still rather slow…… btw I use the shelve to store the dict ,sigh……

Comment: @user1587485, are you using `shelve` to _store_ the dict, or are you using a `shelve`-based dictionary to do your calculations? The second will probably be very slow because it will involve a bunch of disk I/O. Assuming your `MemoryError` issue is cleared up, try just using a plain dictionary.

Comment: ……what's the difference? I just use d=shelve.open('wiki.dat',writeback=True) then I do the for loops to change the values of the keys in d . Is there another way?

Comment: @user1587485, the difference is that `shelve` is two orders of magnitude slower, even with `writeback=True`, at least according to my simple test above.