# Python: Limiting number of elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, scripting, jython

I am using The Grinder and I have a Python script which executes some Java APIs to gather the minimum, maximum, number of executions, and total executions (the latter 2 to get the average execution times). This is done for each API (it's a multidimensional array) and each thread.

```
#Contents of apiTimingsList array: [min, max, number of executions, total execution time]
apiTimingsList = [[9999,0,0,0] for j in range(len(apiList))]
```

I am investigating some memory issues and I think that the growing size of this array might be a problem. It will grow constantly as the test runs. For example, if I have 10 APIs and I am running 900 threads, there are 9000 arrays that will keep growing as long as the test runs.

Is there a way to limit the size of these arrays, to say only keep the last x number of executions so my calculations are still valid but the arrays are not growing out of control?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537618/memory-errors-and-list-limits-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.deque`:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(maxlen=2)
>>> d.append(3)
>>> d.append(4)
>>> d.append(5)
>>> d
    deque([4, 5], maxlen=2)
```

Comment: Thank you - something like this looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A `deque` from the `collections` module will probably accomplish what you want.