# Can Python use the harddrive as extra memory?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, out-of-memory, scikit-learn

I'm running a text machine learning algorithm which generates n-grams. This of course massively balloons the size of the input. To put this in context, the original input is ~30K lines in a file, after generation of trigrams I have 348000 entries.

I'm using `scikit` with its `TfidfVectorizer` and if too many values are given, I get a `MemoryError` thrown by the numpy arrays inside. I'm only able to use ~27500 trigrams before I hit the limit. This means I can only use at most 10% of the available data.

What can I do to help remedy this problem? Do I have any options?

Comment: I believe this is really an operating system question, as it is via the OS that one can allocate a certain amount of disk space as paging or virtual memory. But it will slow things down *incredibly*. It's probably better to either find a machine with more memory, or to rethink your approach altogether.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537618/memory-errors-and-list-limits-in-python) for some information. Make sure you're using 64-bit Python and not 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jme, python has no influence on the OS's memory management.
Probably the most reasonable approach (if you cannot find a machine with more RAM) would be to somehow limit the number of features, e.g. with one of the following options parameters for [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> **max_df** : float in range [0.0, 1.0] or int, default=1.0
>
> When building the vocabulary ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly higher than the given threshold (corpus-specific stop words). If float, the parameter represents a proportion of documents, integer absolute counts. This parameter is ignored if vocabulary is not None.
>
> **min_df** : float in range [0.0, 1.0] or int, default=1
>
> When building the vocabulary ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly lower than the given threshold. This value is also called cut-off in the literature. If float, the parameter represents a proportion of documents, integer absolute counts. This parameter is ignored if vocabulary is not None.
>
> **max_features** : int or None, default=None
>
> If not None, build a vocabulary that only consider the top max_features ordered by term frequency across the corpus.
>
> This parameter is ignored if vocabulary is not None.

Comment: I actually found my problem. It turns out that the vectorizer is very efficient, but if you call toarray() on the vector it kills the memory. Once I realized that, things became better.