# How to load a machinlearning csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have never coded using python and I have to use it for my summer research project.

I'm learning ML(machine learning) techniques and i'm stuck. As you see from the attached picture. 
I can't load a csv file.(which is kdd 99 test data according to UCI KDD Archieve https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html)
Could you please help me solve this problem?

[scan of the file and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPoXy.png)

Comment: Do you know what a ["MemoryError"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537618/memory-errors-and-list-limits) is?

Comment: How big is the file you're trying to load, and how much RAM do you have? Your RAM is less than the size of the file you're trying to load. Also, you ought to read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: Hi alexis : I searched about "MemoryError" which is not enough memory right?

Comment: Hello not_a_robot: Well the size of file is about 16mb and the RAM which I have 8GB.