# Python: How to split np array / list into two arrays / lists without using more RAM

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, out-of-memory

I have a problem with spliting a np. array and list into two. Here is my code:

```
X = []
y = []
for seq, target in ConvertedData:
    X.append(seq)
    y.append(target)

y = np.vstack(y)

train_x = np.array(X)[:int(len(X) * 0.9)]
train_y = y[:int(len(X) * 0.9)]
validation_x = np.array(X)[int(len(X) * 0.9):]
validation_y = y[int(len(X) * 0.9):]
```

This is a sample of code that prepares data for neural network. Works great, but generates "out of memory error" (i have 32GB on board):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/....Here is a file location.../FileName.py", line 120, in <module>
    validation_x = np.array(X)[int(len(X) * 0.9):]
MemoryError
```

It seems like it keeps in memory list *X* and np.array *y* and duplicates it as separate variablest *train_x, train_y, validation_x, validation_y*. Do you know how to deal with this?

Shape of X:(324000, 256, 24)

Shape of y:(324000,10)

Shape of train_x: (291600, 256, 24)

Shape of train_y:(291600,10)

Shape of validation_x:(32400, 256, 24)

Shape of validation_y:(32400,10)

Comment: Are you trying to use files to store training data? You can pick each row to file and do not use ram. What do you think about that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474324/4510954  Moreover, you can use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split to perform your split operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = []
y = []
for seq, target in ConvertedData:
    X.append(seq)
    y.append(target)
```

`X` is a list of `seq`.  I assume those are arrays. `X` just has pointers to those,

```
y = np.vstack(y)

train_x = np.array(X)[:int(len(X) * 0.9)]
```

Makes an array from `X`, and then a slice of that array.  The full `np.array(X)` still exists in memory

```
train_y = y[:int(len(X) * 0.9)]
validation_x = np.array(X)[int(len(X) * 0.9):]
```

Makes another array from `X`.  `train_x` and `validation_x` are views of separate arrays.

```
validation_y = y[int(len(X) * 0.9):]
```

Doing

```
X1 = np.array(X)
train_x = X1[:...]
validation_x = X1[...:]
```

will eliminate that duplication.  Both are views of the same `X1`.

Another approach would be to slice the list first:

```
train_x = np.array(X[:...])
validation_x = np.array(X[...:])
```

My guess is that memory use, at least with in the arrays will be similar.

`del X` after creating the `X1` might also help, allowing `X` and the arrays it references to be garbage collected.

But beware that once you start hitting a memory error at one point in your code, tricks like this might postpone it.   Calculations can easily end up making copies, or temporary buffers, of comparable size.

---

Your split uses 2 slices; that results in views, which don't add to the original memory use.  But if you make a shuffled split, the train and validation parts will be copies, and together take up as much memory as the source.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I used this solution with X1=np.array(X). It also hits max memory, but it takes less than one minute, so there is no memory error and the program is still going. By the way - after creating train and validation arrays I decided to delete arrays X and y and perform gc.collect(). After this memory usage is reduced to 6GB before machine learning started. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As described in [answer of memory errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537764/4510954) You can pickle each array of trainig data to file [like in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474324/4510954)

You can split by [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), it could be more efficient way of performing spliting.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Comment: I think the `sklearn` split takes a random (or shuffled) split, which will result in copies of the source, not views.