# Is it possible to create a 1million x 1 million matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Numpy Very Large Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/python-numpy-very-large-matrices)

I tried numpy.zeros((100k x 100k)) and it returned "array is too big".
Response to comments:
1) I could create 10k x 10k matrix but not 100kx100k and 1milx1mil. 
2) The matrix is not sparse.

Comment: 100k x 100k is 100 times less than 1m x 1m.

Comment: Is it a million x a million or 100k x 100k? What do you mean, too big? You're allocating 10 billion elements, that's going to be big.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697557/numpy-problem-with-long-arrays

Comment: try sparse matrices; see [Python Numpy Very Large Matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/)

Comment: This just begs the question: what do you plan to do with a 1,000,000x1,000,000 matrix anyways?

Answer (score 15):

We can do simple maths to find out. A 1 million by 1 million matrix has 1,000,000,000,000 elements. If each element takes up 4 bytes, it would require 4,000,000,000,000 bytes of memory. That is, 3.64 terabytes.

There are also chances that a given implementation of Python uses more than that for a single number. For instance, just the leap from a float to a double means you'll need 7.28 terabytes instead. (There are also chances that Python stores the number on the heap and all you get is a pointer to it, approximately doubling the footprint, without even taking in account metadata–but that's slippery grounds, I'm always wrong when I talk about Python internals, so let's not dig it too much.)

I suppose `numpy` doesn't have a hardcoded limit, but if your system doesn't have that much free memory, there isn't really anything to do.

Comment: Python does use more than that for a single number (about 10 bytes IIRC), but numpy is written in C and Fortran.

Comment: Just as a side note, the point of numpy is that arrays are compact in memory, so a `numpy.float32` array only takes 4 bytes per element (plus a tiny bit of constant overhead for the whole array).  What you said is quite true for python lists, though!

Comment: People are usually wrong when they ponder the internals of any complex system. Including the ones they built themselves.

Comment: Strictly (according to ISO) that's 3.64 _tibibytes_ and 4 terabytes. But I hate the word “tibibyte” so +1. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Does your matrix have a lot of zero entries? I suspect it does, few people do dense problems that large.

You can easily do that with a sparse matrix. SciPy has a good set built in. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html
The space required by a sparse matrix grows with the number of nonzero elements, not the dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Your system probably won't have enough memory to store the matrix in memory, but nowadays you might well have enough terabytes of free disk space. In that case, [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) would allow you to have the array stored on disk, but appear as if it resides in memory.

However, it's probably best to rethink the problem. Do you really need a matrix this large? Any computations involving it will probably be infeasibly slow, and need to be done blockwise.